# Is it Possible / best practice to scale API Gateway by generating multiple replicas of API Gateway to handle the load?

Tags: load-balancing, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, ca-api-gateway

Is it possible/best practice to scale API Gateway by generating multiple replicas of API Gateway to handle the load ?

By setting a load balancer before the API Gateway, the LB will route the requests to the most available API gateway replica .

Thanks

Comment: No, let Amazon do the load balancing, it's what you're paying them for

Comment: Is this architecture happen on the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it possible?** Yes

**Is it advised?** Absolutely not

Amazon API Gateway's is a multi-tenant service with shared architecture. Each API is **not** serviced by a single resource, but a set of shared resources that scale with overall usage. Implementing load balancing in front of a set of API Gateway APIs within the same region would be redundant and just add an additional network hop to your customers traffic.

Customers are assigned default limits to prevent abuse and for capacity planning, but these limits can be raised if you have a valid business need for them to be.

Comment: Thanks Bob,
"Each API is not serviced by a single resource, but a set of shared resources that scale with overall usage" - so is it actually happening behind the scenes ?